# ListView Cell Expand (Slide Down) animation

Tags: android, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I make a cell in a ListView in Android expand and contract vertically when it’s touched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522348/how-can-i-make-a-cell-in-a-listview-in-android-expand-and-contract-vertically-wh)

I would like to see a good example of a cell view expanding and pushing list items below down like on twitter application.  What I want is user clicks on button in list view item and then the item_view expands gracefully to reveal a EditText and button.

Thanks

Comment: Please try to write some code for that. Then ask for help if you are stuck somewhere

Comment: Do you want code for slide down animation?

Comment: yes that would be great. Slide down to reveal more of the view like edit text and button.  Click on button and it slides back up. Currently I am using dialog boxes, but I prefer continuous inside list experience.

Comment: [Duplicated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12522348/1050058)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this..

```
public class ExpandAnimation extends Animation {
@Override
protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
    super.applyTransformation(interpolatedTime, t);

    // End animation sometimes calls with exactly 1.0f
    if (interpolatedTime <= 1.0f) {

        // Calculating the new bottom margin, and setting it
        mViewLayoutParams.bottomMargin = mMarginStart
                + (int) ((mMarginEnd - mMarginStart) * interpolatedTime);

        // Invalidating the layout, making us seeing the changes we made
        mAnimatedView.requestLayout();
    }
}
```

The code above changes the view's margins in every animation frame. That makes it appear like the your new view is pushing the rest of the items downwards. You can also try changing the subitem's height instead of its margins..

Comment: Ok, how would I apply that to the cell. Also what is the inverse that would make it slide back up.  The other thing I am not clear on is how this margin expansion would make display the previously hidden part of the cell. Namely the EditText and send button.

Comment: So really the cell has an always visible part and the part that becomes visible with the animation.  Not clear on how expanding the margin makes the (previously hidden part of the cell visible).

Comment: for collapsing create another custom animation.. Make the hidden part visible first then run this animation on it.. in onitemclick

Comment: that would be  mViewLayoutParams.bottomMargin = mMarginStart
                - (int) ((mMarginEnd - mMarginStart) * interpolatedTime);  ?

Comment: Should the previously hidden be gone --> visible?

Comment: for expanding make it Visible then start this animation on it.. for collapsing run the collapse animation first then hide the subitem..