# Expand ListItem on click to a new view

Tags: java, android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I have a listview with some texts in it like this

[image: this]

and I want to expand each item to like this

[image: this]

I have seen this answer([How can I make a cell in a ListView in Android expand and contract vertically when it's touched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522348/how-can-i-make-a-cell-in-a-listview-in-android-expand-and-contract-vertically-wh)), here it doesn't changes to a new view, but just changes the height.

UPDATE:`list_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="@drawable/list_selected">

<RelativeLayout

    android:id="@+id/relaboveline1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/sidebar"
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#4ED6CA" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/sidebar"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/sidebar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/cal"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="22"
                    android:textColor="#FF8801"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/month"
                    android:textColor="#FF8801"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/date"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="MAY" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/year"
                    android:textColor="#FF8801"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/month"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:text="2015" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cal"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cal"
                android:background="#DADADA" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="60">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/content"

                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"

                android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:text="High School Graduation" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/contentdesc"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"

                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
                    android:text="@string/dummy" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
               >

                <TextView

                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:textStyle="bold"

                    android:text="5B"
                    android:id="@+id/classDiv" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_below="@+id/classDiv"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/star_yellow" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/line2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.5dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relaboveline1"
    android:background="#DADADA" />
```

Comment: `here it doesn't changes to a new view,` No but in your mentioned example there is only one TextView. I think you have a lot more items. So how did you adapt the code to begin with? Please show your List item layout xml.

Comment: Please answer my comments/questions too. Please tell which part of the layout in the xml you want to make visible/invisible. (Write it as comment in the block).

Comment: I think its pretty clear with the images provided. Expand the listitem and show layout like in the 2nd image.

Answer (score 4):

You can use ExpandableListView:

1. You define a custom layout for the child (the details when you click on the row)
2. You define an `public class ExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter`
3. Override the method

   `public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
           boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ....
   }`

   where you implement your detail layout (child layout).
4. Override the method

   `public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
           View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ...
    }`

   where you implement the layout like the ListView.
5. Set the custom adapter in your ExpandableListView instance

If you want to have more info give a look at my post here http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/01/android-expandablelistview-baseexpandablelistadapter.html

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried ExpandableListView with only one child view for each group view? then you can expand and collapse rows as you want.