# Android - measure height of text

Tags: android, listview

I copied the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522348/how-can-i-make-a-cell-in-a-listview-in-android-expand-and-contract-vertically-wh) and it's working nearly perfectly, the problem is that the author sets the heights of the list items to fixed values, and it isn't displaying correctly on my device.

The code sets the height of the list items to 150, and I thought "Hey, I'll just measure the height of my text" and so I call

```
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG);
Rect bounds = new Rect();
paint.getTextBounds("April 3, 2016", 0, 13, bounds);
Log.d("Fragment.toggle", "Text height is " + bounds.height());
```

and for text that is slightly larger than the 150 fixed value, the text height returned from getTextBounds() is 12.  Since 12 is not "slightly larger" than 150, I've clearly done something wrong.

I've written a lot of software in my life, but this is my first day doing Android development, so I am probably doing something obviously stupid.  I suspect that the two values (150 and 12) are in different units, but I've been poking around in the documentation and can't figure it out.

How can I calculate the height of my text, in whichever units AbsListView.LayoutParams is expecting?

Comment: What are you expecting the Paint object to return for this particular call?  I don't understand how you think something is obviously wrong with it.

Comment: If you want to show text use a TextView, set text size in sp (scaled pixel), Android will do everything else.

Comment: Thanks for jumping in guys, the problem is that I'm enough of an Android newbie that I'm not even sure how to ask the question.  If you follow the link to "this question", it's another StackOverflow page titled "How can I make a cell in a ListView in Android expand and contract vertically when it's touched?".  It has hardcoded values in it for the height of the list items (numbers like 150) and I want to calculate those values instead of hardcoding them.

Comment: So what I'm trying to say, is that my question probably doesn't make a lot of sense, outside of the context of the original StackOverflow question that I am trying to implement.  I didn't think I should add my comment to that question, since my problem is not with their code but my understanding, but maybe that's a better place to ask?

Answer (score 0):

I finally beat this question into submission.

The first part of the answer is that the return code from getTextBounds() is in points (wouldn't it be nice if the documentation said that?).  Dividing that answer by 72 gives my text height in inches, multiplying that by DisplayMetrics.densityDpi gives the text height in pixels.

```
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint.LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG);
Rect bounds = new Rect(0, 0, 10000, 10000);
paint.getTextBounds("April 3, 2016", 0, 13, bounds);
DisplayMetrics dm = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
float textHeightInches = bounds.height() / 72.0f;
float textHeightPixels = textHeightInches * dm.densityDpi;
```

The second part of the answer is that the list item has padding on the top and bottom that must be included when calculating the total height.

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
LinearLayout listItemLayout = (LinearLayout)vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
int collapsedHeight = (int)(textHeightPixels + 0.5f) + listItemLayout.getPaddingTop() + listItemLayout.getPaddingBottom();
```

Now, when I create the ListItem objects, I can pass in my calculated height instead of a fixed number.