# ListView with expandable layout

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

I have a `ListView` with hundreds of `item` in it.

I want when a user taps on a item (`onClick`), it expands and show some details about it.

**But** i want to show a layout, like `RelativeLayout` or a `LinearLayout`.

I suppose I have to make hundreds layouts I guess. Maybe there is a better way?

Because different description for each item (price, country, etc.).

I'm already aware of `ExpandbleListView`

I don't want to use `child.add("Android");` because i want the expanded view to be organized like table view.

So when I click on it, it expand and show a layout.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522348/how-can-i-make-a-cell-in-a-listview-in-android-expand-and-contract-vertically-wh

Answer (score 0):

Build the `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` as a part of your list item view and set the `visibility` to `false` initially.

Now keep track of the items expanded in a global array so set the proper visibility of the expanded views in your list.

I'm sharing some pseudo code which might help you to understand.

```
// Take a global array to keep track of the expanded items in your list
// Lets assume the name of your list is myArrayList
private void int[] expandedItems = new int[myArrayList.size()];

// Now initialize your array with all zeros 
for(int i=0; i<expandedItem.length; i++) 
    expandedItems[i] = 0;
```

Now when a item is clicked update the corresponding position in your `expandedItems` array.

```
itemView.setOnClickListener {
    //....
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        // Set 1 to indicate the corresponding is view is expanded
        expandedItems[position] = 1;
        notifyDatasetChanged();
    }
}
```

Now in your `onBindViewHolder` populate the list as follows

```
if(expandedItems[position] == 1)
    expandedLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else
    expandedLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);  // Don't forget the else part
```