# Expand content inside navigation drawer on navigation item click - android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

In my android app, i am having `NavigationDrawer`. Now, i want that when i click on any navigation-item, then

1) left drawer should remain open

2) previous listitem should be replaced by item-click content

3) item click content should be loaded within navigation view.

I searched but found few links suggesting to use `ExpandableListview`. Is there any facility to expand or collapse content of navigation item? 
Is it according to android design patterns? if its possible then please suggest that how can i achieve it.

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to use list as expanded content ExpandableListview is best otherwise you have to write your own logic.

Comment: but i want navigationview content to be replaced by new content. `ExpandableListView` will provide that facility?

Comment: No u have to write ur own logic

Comment: ok, can you suggest any link or tutorial which i should follow?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522348/how-can-i-make-a-cell-in-a-listview-in-android-expand-and-contract-vertically-wh